# Option from a dropdown not getting selected dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have two dropdowns where the options are coming from an API dynamically. I am trying to select the option dynamically using jquery. The first dropdown gets selected but the second do not.

I am trying to achieve this using `$('#id').find(option [value = ""]).attr(selected, selected);`

These are the HTML fields..

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Branch</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="ddlSelectBranch" data-val="true">
   </select>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">                                                
   <label>User Role</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="ddlSelectRole" data-val="true">
     </select>
 </div>
```

This the Jquery Code..

```
  $('#ddlSelectBranch').find("option[value='" + item.branchDTO.branchId + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
  $('#ddlSelectRole').find("option[value='" + item.roleDTO.roleId + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

This is the object I'm currently working on..

```
branchDTO: {branchId: 6, branchName: "Bandhan Serampore"}
loginId: "BK1234"
roleDTO: {roleId: 1, roleName: "program datector"}
userEmailPrimary: "p.ojha@gmail.com"
userEmailSecondary: ""
userFirstname: "Pragyan"
userId: 25
userLastname: "Ojha"
userMiddlename: "Ganesh"
userMobilePrimary: "9635200456"
userMobileSecondary: "7896523647"
```

The branch field gets selected but it's not working on the role field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `selected` option, just set the value of the dropdown:

```
$("#ddlSelectBranch").val(item.branchDTO.branchId);
$("#ddlSelectRole").val(item.roleDTO.roleId);
```

However, your method should work as well. If it's not working, the problem must be that `item.roleDTO.roleId` doesn't actually match the values of any of the options. Make sure there's no extra whitespace in the option values.

Comment: The problem was actually with document.ready function. However you taught me a shorter way for doing that. Thanks for the help. Keep up the good work.